# Database Design for classifieds site

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm creating a classifieds site where there are many categories and subcategories.
1) Each category has different fields.
2) Each listing has one or more images

I need help with the database design. My current thinking is:

- Listings table. fields: id, image_id etc.
- A table for each category, which would contain a listing_id
- Images table. fields: listing_id
- I'm not sure how I'd go about doing subcategories. I'm a bit of a noob, so I may be on the wrong track altogether.

I'm using postgresql by the way.

Comment: Didn't you post this here or on another stack exchange site recently? Pretty sure I saw just this...

Comment: nope, this is my first post about this

Comment: WRT subcategories, it sounds like they are like classes and subclasses in OOP. If so, check out the answers to [This question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71224/data-modeling-with-many-attributes-where-few-apply-to-each-record/71249#71249).

Comment: I think the minimum you need to do to make this less broad is provide a SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of question (have new project, how do I...) appears frequently here. I will urge you to do what I would urge everybody who has a new project to do - stand on the shoulders of giants.

Check out any/a few/all Open Source projects that do what you are interested in doing (or similar) and learn from their database schemas and adapt what has already been done to your own needs. A quick search gave me this [site](http://osclass.org/) (and this [one](http://open-classifieds.com/)) both of which appears to be interesting from your perspective.

Take a look at them and if there's anything you're having trouble with, post back here. The only (small IMHO) issue is that both of them are MySQL based, but that shouldn't be a major stumbling block.